# browser event handling-only browser/tab close

Tags: javascript, php, event-handling

I need to capture the event of the user closing the browser or tab or going to a different site before the last page of the application so that the PHP session can be unset and database transactions made up to this point can be undone. I have been searching for days and the closest thing I have found is using event.clientX and event.clientY to get the cursor position and eliminating the specific locations of the back, forward, submit, and refresh buttons from my onbeforeunload code. However, this does not seem reliable since the window might not always be the same size for every user. Can anyone help?

```
function beforeUnloadAction(event)
{
     if(event = browser close, tab close, go to a different site)
     {
          //unset the session, rollback database transactions
     }
     else 
     {
         //do nothing 
     }
}
```

Comment: i would say the problem is needing to do this in the first place. why do you think its necessary to unset the session?

Comment: Sorry- I just made an edit to the question. I can clear any existing session data before a new session starts but there could be records in the database that need to be removed if the user does not continue to the last screen. This is the actual reason I need to capture these particular events.

Comment: then you need a separate clean up script, nothing can detect a user walking away for the computer. timestamp entires once a day clean up uncompleted transactions

Comment: There is no way to reliably do this. What if the user's internet goes out? What if they have JavaScript disabled? What if it's a cURL request? HTTP is stateless. You need to handle the case where session is not unset.